# How to perform read and write operations on 20GB excel file on server?

Tags: java, excel, jdbc, apache-poi

I am having few Excel files on server and I want to perform read and write operations on them.

There are two ways I can think of :

1. Use the Apache POI and perform the needful task (I really doubt on this approach as I came across a lot of OutOfMemory issues on stackoverflow where people are struggling to load > 250MB File)
2. Treat each Excel files as a database and use JDBC|ODBC to perform read and write operations. (this approach is better then the 1st one as it doesn't load the whole file on memory)

Sample Operations could be :

- Searching for a string
- Search and replace

Please let me know if you have done something like this before or if you have any idea.

EDIT: File format could be either xls or xlsx, it is not a csv file guys !!!

Comment: 20GB excel file? that's amazing considering that it has following limitation: 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns. I would recommend the database approach as well for a file that large

Comment: Are those really binary `xls`/`xlsx` files, or just `csv` files? The latter you can handle easier because it's just text.

Comment: if it is CSV file we can take bit size file like 20 GB excel file

Comment: just out of curiosity: how do JDBC/ODBC driver work for Excel files? They probably have to load the file in RAM as well. So the memory problem just shifts from your code to the driver.

Comment: @MickMnemonic a 20GB text file would likely cause out of memory errors trying to load it, and be extremely slow to work your way through.

Comment: Apache POI has a streaming mode for Excel files, this might be the best case if you want to search/replace operations, but don't need random access: See SXSSF at https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/

Comment: @Zac that's no limit for the number of cells... You can have a sheer unlimited number of sheets in a file, and then many columns per row per sheet. It's insane, but in theory a 20GB Excel file could exist. Good luck loading it though

Comment: @jwenting, you don't need to (and probably even can't) load the whole file into memory. You should be able to stream through it effortlessly with a regular `BufferedReader`. But OP confirmed that it's a binary file, so probably a streaming library for Excel is the only choice.

Comment: @Soumyaansh please update thread with final solution you crack..that will help me

Comment: @user2572801 will update the answer once the things are figured out and completed.